# Numbers wrongly shown right to left anywhere

Tags: android, numbers, translation, right-to-left, farsi

I'm having a problem with my Huawei y600 Android phone in stock rom. The problem is with numbers. They are shown correctly when language is English (left to right), but when I change the language to Farsi (right to left; My native Language) the numbers go right to left too and thats a totall wrong!

This is the screenshot when the phone is in English:

[image: This is the screenshot when the phone is in English:]

The clock is in the correct format, it shows 18:45. numbers are correct in contacts too:

[image: Screenshot of contacts]

But when language changes clock goes freaky:

[image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/ccsyGoCBba/Screenshot_-----.html]

The clock was 18:56. it shows(in my language) "8164:" note that the ":" mark will go at the end too...and 18 46 will go 81 64. They go right to left same as the texts..but thats wrong... it's worse when in contacts (It's the Same Number):

[image: contacts when farsi]

As you See The 09113924601 Is 4601 392 0911. they all go right to left.

I just tested my phone more an i founded out that this problem is only whit persian not any other right to left language(like arabic),so i think if there is an app or an adb command to make the rom uses arabic numbers while using persian words i think the problem will be fixed cuz arabic and persian numbers are the same.

i tried more locale 2 and i mixed the arabic and persian in ways like arabic in language and iran in country and reverse but didnt worked.

1_is there a program to specify the parameters more accurately like numbers seprate and words seprate?

2_what is "variant" in more locale 2 app?

Comment: Please avoid fillers like "..."!

Comment: wat u use.. `TextView` ??

Comment: Try this link if this helps you http://androidsbs.blogspot.in/2013/11/androidtextdirection.html

Comment: This seems like a software bug in the home-screen program. Note that the clock in the top-right corner seems to display the time correctly, with the colon in the middle of the two numbers.  How does the date/time show in the Settings -> Date/Time settings screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the software implementation of certain stock programs on the device. They most likely haven't been tested correctly in Farsi, yet still make some basic use of language translation features (albeit incorrectly).

I suggest downloading some separate programs from an app store (e.g. Google Play) to replace the stock programs that don't work correctly for you... so find a new launcher program, and a new contacts program.

Comment: no,it wont work.i tried another clock app,still showing wrong:http://www.4shared.com/photo/RiaE4MDHba/Screenshot_-----.html

Comment: @MohsenHasannezhad so you're saying that if you download Google Calendar (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar), with language set to Farsi, that Google Calendar doesn't display dates/times/numbers correctly? Is the output the same?

Comment: i tried the clock app,if want let me try google calendar too,1 min.

Comment: no,that doesnt work too.http://www.4shared.com/download/tFOI-V-Yce/Screenshot_-----.png?lgfp=3000

Comment: it says october 4102,but it should be 2014!

Comment: I have one more suggestion... Try using this Locale Setter program to change the date/time format (rather than doing it through Android Settings). It exposes more options. I did this to change my phone language to British English, which wasn't an option on the stock ROM that I use. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.set.locale&hl=en

Comment: Possible other resource: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/help-getting-arabic-on-android  There are some links mentioned there ( http://ardroid.com/  /  http://www.needrom.com/category/huawei/y600/ ) that might be useful.